# Docker containers that are not running on localhost

Tags: docker

For regular docker containers (say the hello world example), after you run it, it is accessible thought localhost, where you can make a request it through your browser.

But sometimes it seems to access a container you need a special IP address. I'm wondering what's this behavior of docker container networking called and where is it defined/documented.

Let's say my local ip address is 10.0.75.1 (got from Network properties in Windows settings named, vEthernet (DockerNAT)). But in order to connect to a container running I had to use ip address 10.0.75.2. Why is this?

If try to inspect existing docker networks using `docker network [cmd]`, the containers seem to be on different subnets, for example '172.17.0.0/16'

Comment: Did you use a `docker run -p` option or Docker Compose `ports:` option when you started the container?  Trying to use the Docker-internal IP addresses like this is usually wrong: it doesn’t work on some platforms (Docker Toolbox, Docker for Mac) or from other hosts.

Comment: It's using docker compose. I don't understand why some can be accesible through localhost some need to use special ip address like this one

Comment: Do you have an example of a service that you can't access via `localhost` that you expect to?

Comment: Don't have an example that I can post. But I think it might be because Docker on windows runs on a VM, and 172.17.0.0 is containers' internal subnet. It's accessible from host machine because daemon has some mapping to expose it (the DockerNAT vEthernet) https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/221